# UIAlertController EXC_BAD_ACCESS error - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to use a UIAlertController in Swift, with iOS 7, and I keep getting the following error when the alert should appear:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x10)

Here is the code for the alert.

```
var alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Ooops", message: "Please Fill In Everything", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) is available only since **iOS 8.0**. You should still use `UIAlertView` instead

Comment: Gaaaah... so many newly available features I'm trying to use so that my work is up to date but they're not compatible with iOS 7.  =/